# can anyone tell me what is wrong with my if condition?

Tags: python

```
import random
end_of_game = False
word_list = ["ardvark", "baboon", "camel"]
chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)
word_length = len(chosen_word)
lives = 6
#Testing code
print(f'Pssst, the solution is {chosen_word}.')
display = []
for _ in range(word_length):
    display += "_"
while end_of_game == False:
    guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
    for position in range(word_length):
        letter = chosen_word[position]
        if letter == guess:
            display[position] = letter
    if guess != chosen_word:
        lives -= 1
        if lives == 0:
            end_of_game = True
            print("You lose.")
    print(f"{' '.join(display)}")
    if "_" not in display:
        end_of_game = True
        print("You win.")
```

I have a problem with this part only

```
if guess != chosen_word: 
    lives -= 1 
    if lives ==0        
        end_of_game = True
```

when ever i picked a wrong word then my lives should go down but no matter what if only gives me 6 tries what am i doing wrong'''
enter code here

Comment: `guess` is just a single character, `chosen_word` is the whole word. So they will never be equal.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if guess != chosen_word:
```

to

```
if guess not in chosen_word:
```

so then you only lose a life if the letter you guessed is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing one letter `guess` to the whole word `chosen_word`. They'll never be equal, so you always decrement `lives`.

Instead, check if `_` is still in `display`, just as you do when determining whether to display `You win`.

```
if "_" in display:
    lives -= 1
    if lives == 0:
        end_of_game = True
        print("You lose.")
```

Comment: Thank you for your hep and editing my comment i am new to this website and python language.